# How to get response field as json instead of string?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have a `GET` endpoint deployed using AWS CDK python as lambda function with API Gateway.

```
def get_all_farms(self, event, context):
    params = event["queryParams"]
    offset = int(params["offset"] or 0)
    max = int(params["max"] or 20)
    result = db.get_all_farms_paginated(offset, max)
    return {
        "error": False,
        "message": "success",
        "farms": json.dumps(result, default=str),
    }
```

I have this code. This is giving response like:

```json
{
    "error": false,
    "message": "success",
    "farms": "[{\"id\": 2, \"name\": \"Central Grain\", \"address1\": \"1140 W Locust St\", \"address2\": \"\", \"city\": \"Belvidere\", \"state\": \"IL\", \"county\": \"Boone County\", \"latitude\": \"42.2526532\", \"longitude\": \"-88.85798849999999\", \"created_date\": \"2023-09-25 22:35:17\"}, {\"id\": 3, \"name\": \"Central Grain\", \"address1\": \"1140 W Locust St\", \"address2\": \"\", \"city\": \"Belvidere\", \"state\": \"IL\", \"county\": \"Boone County\", \"latitude\": \"42.2526532\", \"longitude\": \"-88.85798849999999\", \"created_date\": \"2023-09-25 22:39:54\"}, {\"id\": 4, \"name\": \"Central Grain\", \"address1\": \"1140 W Locust St\", \"address2\": \"\", \"city\": \"Belvidere\", \"state\": \"IL\", \"county\": \"Boone County\", \"latitude\": \"42.2526532\", \"longitude\": \"-88.85798849999999\", \"created_date\": \"2023-09-25 22:48:46\"}]"
}
```

I want to get the farms as json instead of string. If I pass the result directly in the response, I get date conversion error. And the fix for that suggests to use json.dumps. I am not sure how to get json response. Please help. Thanks.

---

CDK code for `GET`

```
myfarm_resource.add_method(
    "GET",
    integration=apigateway.LambdaIntegration(
        api_lambda_myfarm,
        proxy=False,
        passthrough_behavior=apigateway.PassthroughBehavior.WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES,
        request_templates={
            "application/json": request_template,
        },
        integration_responses=[
            apigateway.IntegrationResponse(
                status_code="200",
            )
        ],
    ),
    method_responses=[
        apigateway.MethodResponse(
            status_code="200",
        )
    ],
)
```

Comment: 'If I pass the result directly in the response, I get date conversion error. ' - can you show us that exact version of the code and the exact error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not efficient in the slightest but the following will fix the issue:

`'farms': json.loads(json.dumps(result, default=str))}`

Unfortunatly, I have this in a bunch of places despite it requiring serializing and deserializing the returned dictionary twice. What you give back to the lambda agent gets thrown into `json.dumps()` without the ability to control the encoders [(docs here)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html#:%7E:text=If%20the%20handler%20returns%20objects%20that%20can%27t%20be%20serialized%20by%20json.dumps%2C%20the%20runtime%20returns%20an%20error.)). So if you want to control the deserialization (in your case specifying `default=str` to handle the date times) its simpler serialize twice.